# gevent queue does not raise Empty when queue.get invoked inside greenlets (other than the main greenlet)?

Tags: python, concurrency, gevent

I am very new to gevent and my question might even be very naive, but the when I run following code I get queue empty exception.

**case 1** makes sense

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

q = gevent.queue.Queue(maxsize=10)

try:
    q.get(timeout=1)
except gevent.queue.Empty:
    print("main greenlet queue empty")
```

but if I run following code I do not get any timeout and code just never invokes any exceptions and I never enter the exception handeling block, in fact code doesn't even wait for 1 sec to fetch data from queue. I just executes immediately with the shown output.

**case 2**

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

q = gevent.queue.Queue(maxsize=10)

def worker(idx):
    print("worker", idx)
    try:
        q.get(timeout=1)
    except gevent.queue.Empty:
        print("worker", idx, "queue empty")

workers = [gevent.spawn(worker, i) for i in range(1)]
```

this outputs:

```
worker 0
```

However, if I call get in the main greenlet with a call to queue.get in both child and main greenlet like following, the behaviour now changes back to normal.

**case 3**

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

q = gevent.queue.Queue(maxsize=10)

def worker(idx):
    print("worker", idx)
    try:
        q.get(timeout=1)
    except gevent.queue.Empty:
        print("worker", idx, "queue empty")

workers = [gevent.spawn(worker, i) for i in range(1)]

try:
    q.get(timeout=1)
except gevent.queue.Empty:
    print("main greenlet queue empty")
```

I get following output.

```
worker 0
main greenlet queue empty
worker 0 queue empty
```

I fail to understand that why does case 2 not raise an exception, can some one please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

I am using python 3.7 and gevent '21.1.2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second case, you are starting greenlets (the interpreter exits after). Adding `joinall()` makes your code wait for the spawned greenlets to return:

```
q = gevent.queue.Queue(maxsize=10)

def worker(idx):
    print("worker", idx)
    try:
        q.get(timeout=1)
    except gevent.queue.Empty:
        print("worker", idx, "queue empty")


print(q.empty())
workers = [gevent.spawn(worker, i) for i in range(1)]
# waiting for them to finish, works as expected!
gevent.joinall(workers)
```

Out:

```
True
worker 0
worker 0 queue empty
```

Comment: While your answer does solve my problem, I also found another solution which was to use non blocking call to get from queue `q.get_noblock`. However one question still bugs me, greenlets are not multiple threads, right? then if it is just one thread why do we need to join it?

Comment: There is always something like a main thread, so there is always one. Additionally, `gevent.spawn` explicitly runs something in a thread. If you need `join` doesn't depend on the number of threads rather than if you need to wait for it to finish.